# Unit: How to write test case using jUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am very new to Mockito and jUnit and TDD in general and I try to learn the right way to do TDD. I need couples of example to kick start my brain. SO please help me

So I have a method `getNameInc(String dirPath, String filenName)`. So given a fileName like `bankAccount.pdf`, and if in this folder, no file name `bankAccount.pdf`, then return `bankAccountAA.pdf`. If there is exist one `bankAccount.pdf` then `return bankAccountBB.pdf` The `increment` is `AA-ZZ`. When it reach `ZZ` then it roll back to `AA`. I already implement the logic of this method. How do I unit test this method using Mockiti and jUnit?

**EDIT**

Here is the class and methods that are involved.

```
public class PProcessor{

    private final Map<Integer, String> incMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    private String getNameInc(String dirPath, String filenName){
         String[] nameList = new File(dirPath).list(new FilenameFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
                //only load pdf files
                return (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"));
            }
        });
        //Return the number of occurance that a given file name appear
        //inside the output folder.
        int freq = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<nameList.length; i++){

            if(fileName.equals(nameList[i].substring(0, 8))){
                freq++;
            }
        }
        return incMap.get(freq);
    }

    private void generateIncHashMap(){
        incMap.put(new Integer(0), "AA");
        incMap.put(new Integer(1), "BB");
        incMap.put(new Integer(2), "CC");
        ...
    }
}
```

`generateIncHashMap()` will be called in the constructor to pre-generate the hash map

Comment: I think you're missing the point of a mock.  A mock shouldn't implement any logic.  Generally it will just return hard coded values based on the test case it's being used in.

Comment: @Mike: I already implement the logic. The method `getNameInc(String dirPath, String fileName)` is already implemented by me. I just wonder how to unit test it. It can either be mockito or plain old jUnit. I try to learn the idea.

Comment: glad you want to use TDD!  But sounds from your last comment like you've written the logic first... which is the opposite way TDD works.  First write a test that fails, then make the test pass with real code, then refactor that code so it's cleaner but doesn't do any more than pass the test.  Then write another failing test.  Mockito is there to help you stub-out complex services that your class depends on.  Can you update your question with the classes that are collaborating on this feature?

Comment: @alpian: I update my post with some codes. Can you take a look at them.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to test your getNameInc(..) method, I assume. When you call it, it looks for the files in the directory you specify, and based on what it finds, decorates the name you gave it.

To make the class unit-testable, you should abstract the dependency on the file system, so that in a mock, you can simulate whatever directory contents you want. Your class will accept an instance of this interface as a dependency, and call it to find out what's in the directory. When you use the class in your program for real, you will supply an implementation of this interface that delegates to the JDK filesystem calls. When you unit-test the class, you will supply Mockito mocks of this interface.

Avoid putting too much logic into the FilesystemImpl class, since you can't write a strict unit test for it. Keep it a very simple wrapper around the filesystem, so that all the intelligent stuff is in Yourclass, which you will write plenty of unit tests for.

```
public interface Filesystem {
    boolean contains(String dirpath, String filename);
}

public class FilesystemImpl {
    boolean contains(String dirpath, String filename) {
        // Make JDK calls to determine if the specified directory has the file.
        return ...
    }
}

public class Yourmainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Filesystem f = new FilesystemImpl();
         Yourclass worker = new Yourclass(f);
         // do something with your worker
         // etc...
    }
}

public class Yourclass {
    private Filesystem filesystem;

    public Yourclass(Filesystem filesystem) {
        this.filesystem = filesystem;
    }

    String getNameInc(String dirpath, String filename) {
       ...
       if (filesystem.contains(dirpath, filename) {
          ...
       }
    }

}

public class YourclassTest {

   @Test
   public void testShouldAppendAAWhenFileExists() {
       Filesystem filesystem = Mockito.mock(Filesystem.class);
       when(filesystem.contains("/some/mock/path", "bankAccount.pdf").thenReturn(true);
       Yourclass worker = new Yourclass(filesystem);
       String actual = worker.getNameInc("/some/mock/path", "bankAccount.pdf");
       assertEquals("bankAccountAA.pdf", actual);
   }

   @Test
   public void testShouldNotAppendWhenFileDoesNotExist {
       Filesystem filesystem = Mockito.mock(Filesystem.class);
       when(filesystem.contains("/some/mock/path", "bankAccount.pdf").thenReturn(false);
       Yourclass worker = new Yourclass(filesystem);
       String actual = worker.getNameInc("/some/mock/path", "bankAccount.pdf");
       assertequals("bankAccount.pdf", actual);
   }
}
```

Since there's a lot of duplication between the tests, you'd probably create a setup method and do some of the work there, and create some instance variables for the tests to use:

```
    private static final String TEST_PATH = "/some/mock/path";
    private static final String TEST_FILENAME = "bankAccount.pdf";
    private Filesystem filesystem;
    private Yourclass worker;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        filesystem = Mockito.mock(Filesystem.class);
        worker = new Yourclass(filesystem);
    }

    @Test
   public void testShouldAppendAAWhenFileExists() {
       when(filesystem.contains(TEST_PATH, TEST_FILENAME).thenReturn(true);
       String actual = worker.getNameInc(TEST_PATH, TEST_FILENAME);
       assertEquals("bankAccountAA.pdf", actual);
   }

   etc...
```

Comment: shouldnt `FilesystemImpl` a class that implements `Filesystem` rather than an `interface`?

Answer (score 5):

For what you have described there I wouldn't bother with Mockito, there doesn't seem to be anything to mock (because it is easy to manipulate the file system).

I would test ...
 - What happens if I call getNameInc and there are no matching files already
 - What happens if I call getNameInc and there are files AA-YY there already
 - What happens if I call getNameInc and file ZZ is there already

The point of TDD though is that you should have already written these tests and then implemented your code to make the tests pass. So you won't really be doing TDD since you already have the code.

Comment: Yeah, I know that implement test after code does not make a lot of sense, but since this is new to me. I am trying to get a hold of TDD